# How to include Angular2 application from a Laravel view

Tags: laravel, angular

I am building a SAAS app which is multi-tenant (thus, multiple client domains).

It's a Laravel 5.4 + Angular2 project.

My goal is to be able to include angular2 in my base template (base.blade.php).

My current directory setup:

```
xyz-app/
    - laravel/
    - angular/
```

Currently, from the angular folder, I am running

```
ng build -dev --watch --sourcemap=false --output-path="../laravel/public/dist/ng"
```

But, with this I have two problems:

- I loose the `ng watch` goodies.
- `--watch` does not work as expected, for some reason.
- I have to maintain two different projects.

Is there a way to do:

1. Bring angular under the laravel directory
2. Include angular files from laravel blade.

Answer (score 0):

You will find two schools of thought: those that say "yeah, no problem - just integrate Angular into your app layout and use it as you should and consume the routes on the laravel backend" and those who feel it should be two different systems and decoupled.

Decoupling lends itself to more speed and using angular the way it was intended - coupling the two lends itself to more murkiness and makes some tasks much more complicated than needed.

If you're dead set on using them together - you're not alone (I have for a couple projects).

You can check here for a good starting point: https://www.laravel-angular.io/

It's Laravel 5.1 I believe - but it has a lot of the guesswork and legwork taken out of integrating the two and making it work like you would want it to.

Lots of ways to do what you're asking - although 'best practice' would probably leave the two decoupled. Personally? I don't mind them coupled.

Comment: I am all for decoupling the two. I would only use Laravel to serve the index page for the domain and nothing else. The problem with angular being a JS framework is that it would take some time (few secs) to fetch the site configs (site name, title, custom css & translations). And, if laravel is the one serving the index page, I can just send the rendered view which already contains the values rather than angular making an HTTP request and getting them.

Comment: Agreed. So in your home.blade.php or index.blade.php (or whatever) - throw ng-app where you need it and then your controllers and whatever else you need and work from within the blade file perhaps?

That's what I've done a time or two and it's been alright (although these were small applications); then I just call to my API I've defined in laravel as needed.